# Why am I getting a Class cast error? (HIBERNATE)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Product class that has a child class InventoryProduct. They are connected by a upc (Universal Product Code) in the database. Here is the Product class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private long id;

private String upc;

private Category category;

private String name;

private String description;

private BigDecimal price;

public Product(){

}

public Product(String upc){
    this.upc = upc;
}

public Product(String upc, String name, BigDecimal price){
    this.upc = upc;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public Product(String upc, Category category, String name, String description, BigDecimal price) {
    super();
    this.upc = upc;
    this.category = category;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name = "upc")
public String getUpc() {
    return upc;
}

public void setUpc(String upc) {
    this.upc = upc;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Column(name = "price")
public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

And here is the InventoryProduct class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_INVENTORY")
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class InventoryProduct extends Product {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private long id;

private Product product;

private int stock;

public InventoryProduct(){

}

public InventoryProduct(Product product) {
    super(product.getUpc(), product.getCategory(), product.getName(), product.getDescription(), product.getPrice());
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InventoryProduct(Product product, int stock) {
    super(product.getUpc(), product.getCategory(), product.getName(), product.getDescription(), product.getPrice());
    this.stock = stock;
}

public InventoryProduct(String upc, int stock){
    setUpc(upc);
    this.stock = stock;
}

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "stock")
public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="upc", referencedColumnName = "upc", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}
}
```

What I am trying do is to do an inner join between these two objects. Here is my query:

```
public static final String HQL_GET_INVENTORY_PRODUCT = "from InventoryProduct as ip inner join ip.product as p where ip.upc = :upc";
```

And here is where I use this query:

```
@Override
public InventoryProduct getInventoryProductByUpc(String upc) {

    InventoryProduct product = null;

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery(DAOQuery.HQL_GET_INVENTORY_PRODUCT)
                             .setParameter("upc", upc);

        product = (InventoryProduct) query.getSingleResult();

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return product;
}
```

I don't know why I am getting this kind of Class cast error:

```
Oct 19, 2016 11:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/spring-machine-problem] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.qbryx.domain.InventoryProduct] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.qbryx.domain.InventoryProduct
at com.qbryx.dao.ProductDaoHQLImpl.getInventoryProductByUpc(ProductDaoHQLImpl.java:104)
at com.qbryx.service.CustomerServiceImpl.addProductInCart(CustomerServiceImpl.java:44)
at com.qbryx.controller.CustomerController.productCart(CustomerController.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks. I've been stuck here for hours already.

**EDIT**

Here is where the exception points to:

```
product = (InventoryProduct) query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I suppose ` product = (InventoryProduct) query.getSingleResult();` is lead to exception, right?

Comment: yes! I'm sorry for not saying that. It's exactly that line.

Comment: The query is returning an Object array (Object[]) and not the InventoryProduct, which might happen if this is a data selecting query rather than one for just entities.  I'd recommend you add what you are looking to be returned to the query string using JPQL rather than omit it with HQL, and turn on logging to see what is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSingleResult` returns array of object, i suppose first element of this arrai is your product.

```
Object[] arr = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
if(arr.length == 0) {
    product = null;
} else {
    product = (InventoryProduct)arr[0];
}
```

You can use method that return list (`getResult` as far as I remember) it save you one cast.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! But I don't get it. I've used this method in other parts of the program and I didn't need to cast it in an array of object. Thanks bud!

Comment: Yes. It surprised me to. Maybe it is because in this situation result is not single element. Try add `select` clause with `distinct` modifier to your `HQL`.